# How to animate bezier path in WinRT in XAML

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am new to WinRT and XAML and have even less experience with animations. After researching the topic I have noticed that I can change a few individual properties on the storyboard target object as the animation is traversed. What I really need to to change an entire set of bezier path points with each frame to produce an entirely new sine type wave with random amplitudes and control points. Each amplitude's height would be random to approximate a sound wave at a given point in time and the animation is the changing sound patterns over time. All of the examples that I have seen are animations changing a property along the bezier path and traversing the path with each frame. I need to animate changing all the bezier points with each frame. Can I use a storyboard here or do I just need to draw a canvas on some kind of timer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it in XAML and for your problem it seems like an immediate mode rendering technology like Direct2D would be a better choice. I think the Path controls in XAML don't have the performance characteristic required for real-time waveform rendering.

Since you seem to want to animate it with a `Storyboard` - it seems like you might be thinking of a predetermined animation anyways and in that case perhaps you could simply use a video recording of such animation.

Otherwise - you could use the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event to update your path in each frame using code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The wave transitions recreate a random waveform after a random duration to give the appearance having a relationship to a melody so I can't use a video since it is static. It's now working using timers and the dispatcher but when deployed to a surface-RT the degradation makes it unusable (it works fine on my laptop and the Surface). There are four bezier paths on the screen which start the animations when touched and by the time the fourth is touched on the Surface-RT it slows to a crawl.

Comment: I abandoned the storyboard route because there was no dependency property I could use to animate on without creating one and I don't know that I would see much of an improvement by doing that. I'm assuming that would move some of the processing to the rendering thread. I believe it would still end up being a dependent animation which doesn't seem to perform ideally.  It looks like DirectX coding requires that I learn C++ and that could take a bit. For CompositionTarget.Rendering it looks like the layout can't change but it does seem like I can write to a canvas, right?

Comment: I took one more stab at using the storyboard and created my own property on my usercontrol called "Frame" declaring as a double hoping that I could animate using DoubleAnimation to animate 5 or so frames varying the amplitudes to give the illusion of oscillation. It seems that DoubleAnimation ignores my own property but if I try the usercontrols width it works. Is there some special way I need to declare the property other than as a dependency property?

Comment: You need to set `EnableDependentAnimation` to true on animations targeting custom properties.

Comment: It's important to mention that if you set EnableDependentAnimation to true you'll use the UI thread rather than the compositor thread to render your animation. Ultimately this means your UIthread will be more busy than usual and your UI could easily end up losing frames causing 'lag'.